# Build fltk 1.3.4 for Code blocks 16.01

Tags: codeblocks, fltk

Please can anyone direct me on steps to use cmake GUI to build fltk compatible to be used with code blocks. If it as been asked before just direct me there, I've searched but was unsuccessful. Thanks.

Comment: Do you specifically want to use cmake?  Codeblocks can create projects from visual studio solutions.  Just use the solutions in the IDE directory and see how you get on.

Comment: I want to specifically use cmake. I don't have visual studio installed. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need visual studio - codeblocks can import visual studio solutions. 
 There is a make but you need to run configure first - that will set up the configuration file for you.  FLTK already has makefiles.  You may be able to convert them to cmake..

Comment: Can you pls outline the steps to do this